# Read data from multiple USB ports on Android, using cordovarduino

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, serial-port

I am building a `Cordova` App on Android (v5.1.1) that reads data from sensors through the serial/USB ports. Using the `Cordova` plugin, `xseignard/cordovarduino`, I can get data from either port A or port B, but not both concurrently.

Here is a code snippet that I tested, it will gets data from port B but not port A. In the `registerReadCallback`, both ports are invoking the same function process Data.

```
serial.requestPermission(
    portAInfo,
    function(successMessage) {
        console.log("Permission for port A aquired!");

        serial.open(
            {baudRate: 460800},
            // if port is succesfuly opened
            function(successMessage) {
                console.log("port A opened!");

                serial.registerReadCallback(
                    function(data) {
                        // read data from port A
                        processData(data)
                    },
                    errorHandler
                );

                serial.requestPermission(
                    portBInfo,
                    // if user grants permission
                    function(successMessage) {
                        console.log("Permission for port B acquired!");

                        serial.open(
                            {baudRate: 460800},
                            // if port is successfully opened
                            function(successMessage) {
                                console.log("port B opened!");

                                serial.registerReadCallback(
                                    function(data) {
                                        // read data from port B
                                        processData(data)
                                    },
                                    errorHandler
                                );
                            }
                        );
                    }, errorHandler
                )
            }, errorHandler
        );
    }, errorHandler
);
```

It might be that "serial" is only bound with `portBInfo` after opening port B, so calling `serial.registerReadCallback` will never get data from port A.

I know this is specifically related to the library, but if anyone came across this problem before, please give me some advice on this one.